# How do I use UITextfield to handle bi-directional languages (e.g. Arabic)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, arabic

how to change `UITextfield` text Direction from right to Left for other languages in `objective C`?

I want `Arabic` Text to be written from right to left in `UITextfield`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [self.textField setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];?

Comment: By using an Arabic keyboard (you can try it in the simulator), the textfield will automatically insert the characters from right to left. You could align the text to the right as well by using the textAlignment property of UITextField as others stated.

Comment: it will do automatically. No need to right align. Yes but you might need to right align you `UILable`

Comment: TxtField.textAlignment=UITextWritingDirectionRightToLeft; worked but the cursor switch to middle of uitextfield not to the  right of textfield